# how to accept only 1 connection in socket

Tags: java, sockets

Hi i have this code of the server and i added the if to check if ocupado(busy) is = 0, accept socket, if its open busy = 1, so reject till the first user finish the connection, but dont work...

```
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author www
 */
public class ServidorTCPBasico {
static int ocupado = 0; // = busy var to check
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

      // Instancia o ServerSocket ouvindo a porta 9000

      ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(9000);

      System.out.println("Servidor ouvindo a porta 9000");

      while(true) {

        // o método accept() bloqueia a execução até que

        // o servidor receba um pedido de conexão
        Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
        if(ocupado == 0) { 

        int ocupado = 1;
        System.out.println("Cliente conectado: " + cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
System.out.println(ocupado);
        ObjectOutputStream saida = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());

        saida.flush();

//        saida.writeObject(new Date());
        saida.writeUTF("TEXTO TESTE PARA TRANSFERIR...");
        saida.close();

      //  cliente.close();

        }  else { 
            System.out.println("Ocupado");
          }

      }   
    }


    catch(Exception e) {

       System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());

    } 

    finally {
    }  


  }     

}
```

so my question is how to make the socket to accept onnly one connection per time, and THE SERVER close the connection when the user press OK in a confirm box..

the part of confirm box etc.. i will add, my problem is the "logic" or command to allow only one connection, when the client try, it refuse the connection, i will treat the refused connection in the client later

Comment: To be honest, you server should only be capable of "accepting" a single connection at a time, because you are dealing with the current connection within the "accept" thread...

Comment: @MadProgrammer so i have to add everything in a single thread?

Comment: If your goal is prevent multiple connections from being accepted at once, yes.  While `servidor.accept()` is not being called, not other connections will be accepted.  They may be pooled and eventually timed out, but none will be able to interact with the server until `servidor.accept()` is called again...

Answer (score 1):

As per the [JavaDocs for ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html), you can set a backlog as the 2nd parameter.  If requests exceed this backlog they are simply refused.  As per this line:

```
The maximum queue length for incoming connection indications (a request to connect) is set to the backlog parameter. If a connection indication arrives when the queue is full, the connection is refused
```

So, you can try the following:

```
ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(9000, 1);
```

Comment: i tryed it now, dont worked, still can connect multiple times :( and i checked client and server, no one has close(), for nothing :(

Comment: This is per the JavaDocs.  I can't imagine they're wrong. There might be something else going on in your code.

Comment: No. The Javadoc clearly states that "the `backlog` argument is the *requested* maximum length" [my emphasis]. The platform can adjust the requested backlog up or down, and there is no way of determining whether it did so or what the final value is. I'm not aware of a platform where you can set it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You're already ensuring that, by having a single-threaded server. You can't get back to the `accept()` call until you've finished with the previous client. There is no need for your `occupado` test at all.